# How to get the alias(name) and content of of a Cell for MS Excel by using Apache POI

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, loops, apache-poi

I have this excel Sheet where users input information about a geometrical shape. As you can see cell C:3 has been named "Shape"  and the value is triangle. 
[image]

The first part of the code can pull up the names of the cells,  and the following block can print the value inside a specific cell or range. I want to be able to pass those names that the first code pulled  , instead of hard coding them into  String cname . In other words String cname should equal all the values that my first loop pulled, Maybe a nested loop ?

public class RangeSetter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // File Location
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("test2.xls"));

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file); // retrieve workbook

    // This part of the code pulls all the names of the cells
    int NameTotalNumber = wb.getNumberOfNames();
    for (int NameIndex = 0; NameIndex < NameTotalNumber; NameIndex++) {
        Name nameList = wb.getNameAt(NameIndex);
        System.out.println("AliasName: " + nameList.getNameName());

    }

    // This part reads a cell depending of the name

    // This is string has the name of the cell I want to read
    String cname = "Shape";
    // Retrieve the named range
    int namedCellIdx = wb.getNameIndex(cname);
    Name aNamedCell = wb.getNameAt(namedCellIdx);
    AreaReference[] arefs = AreaReference.generateContiguous(aNamedCell
            .getRefersToFormula());
    for (int i = 0; i < arefs.length; i++) {
        // Only get the corners of the Area
        // (use arefs[i].getAllReferencedCells() to get all cells)
        CellReference[] crefs = arefs[i].getAllReferencedCells();
        for (int j = 0; j < crefs.length; j++) {
            // Check it turns into real stuff
            Sheet s = wb.getSheet(crefs[j].getSheetName());
            Row r = s.getRow(crefs[j].getRow());
            Cell c = r.getCell(crefs[j].getCol());
            if (c != null) {
                switch (c.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(c.getStringCellValue());

                }

            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working with your code?

Comment: @Gagravarr I want my code to be able to associate the cell alias and its content and print it out together. I hope that makes more sense. Thanx :)

Comment: A `Named Range` refers to one or more cells, so for a named range get the cell(s) of interest, then print them out as you would do any other cell. Your code looks roughly OK to me (other than not handling the full range of cell types)